# Android persistent imageview across tabbed view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview

I have a tabbed view activity, which lets me scroll through 7 tabs (just the android studio auto generated tabbed view, nothing fancy but included for completeness)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment1());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment2());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment3());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment4());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment5());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment6());
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment7());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

}
```

Is it possible to place an imageview at the bottom of the tabs that will remain in place when swiping left and right between the tabs? i.e. the imageview stays in place, as though it were floating above the fragments in the tabs, and the rest of the content moves

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be simple, but I'll post it here anyways in the hope that it will help someone

To have an image at the bottom which remains persistent (does not move) across the tabs, just put the image in the layout of the tabbed activity, and it will be drawn over all of the tabs.